# Как выбрать таблицу mysql через выпадающий список и записать данные в неё?

Tags: php, html, mysql, форма, запись

Здравствуйте имеется html страница с формой записи и в ней есть элемент select (выпадающий список). Также имеются две таблицы в БД mysql: dentist и therapist. В таблицу therapist данные с формы отправляются и вносятся - с этим проблем нет, написан обработчик для формы записи который и вносит данные в эту таблицу. Как сделать выбор из двух таблиц и внести данные в выбранную таблицу. Пожалуйста помогите. Заранее благодарен.

Форма записи:

```
<form method="post" action="message.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Ваше имя">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="surname" required placeholder="Ваша фамилия">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="middlename" required placeholder="Ваше отчество">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="policynumber" required placeholder="Ваш номер полиса">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="snils" required placeholder="Ваш снилс">
    <br>
    Выберите врача
    <select name="doctor">
        <option value="therapist" selected>Терапевт</option>
        <option value="dentist" selected>Стоматолог</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="date" name="dateofbirth" required placeholder="Дата рождения">
    <br><br>
<input id="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить данные"><br/>
</form>
```

Обработчик формы message.php:

```
<?php
$surname = $_POST['surname'];
$middlename = $_POST['middlename'];
$dateofbirth = $_POST['dateofbirth'];
$policynumber = $_POST['policynumber'];
$snils = $_POST['snils'];
try {
$dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Registry', 'root');
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo "Нет соединения с базой данных";
}
try {
$dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
$dbh->beginTransaction();
$dbh -> exec("INSERT INTO therapist( name, surname, middlename, dateofbirth, policynumber, snils) VALUES ( '$name', '$surname', '$middlename',
'$dateofbirth', '$policynumber', $snils)");
} catch (Exception $e) {
$dbh-> rollBack();
}
header('Refresh:5; URL=http://localhost/site/site.html');
echo 'Данные были полученны';
{
$dbh->commit();
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Судя по вашему коду, так:

**Форма** (обратите внимание на выбор доктора):

```
<form method="post" action="message.php">
    <input type="text" name="name" required placeholder="Ваше имя">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="surname" required placeholder="Ваша фамилия">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="middlename" required placeholder="Ваше отчество">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="policynumber" required placeholder="Ваш номер полиса">
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="snils" required placeholder="Ваш снилс">
    <br>
    Выберите врача
    <select name="doctor">
        <option value="1" selected>Терапевт</option>
        <option value="2">Стоматолог</option>
    </select>
    <br>
    <br>
    <input type="date" name="dateofbirth" required placeholder="Дата рождения">
    <br><br>
    <input id="submit" type="submit" value="Отправить данные"><br/>
</form>
```

**Скрипт:**

```
<?php
// !!!Не забываем фильтрвать пользовательский ввод!!!
// Хотя бы так (PHP 5 >= 5.2.0, PHP 7):
$surname = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'surname', <filter>);
$middlename = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'middlename', <filter>);
$dateofbirth = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'dateofbirth', <filter>);
$policynumber = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'policynumber', <filter>);
$snils = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'snils', <filter>);
// <filter> - Идентификатор (ID) применяемого фильтра. На странице Типы фильтров приведен список доступных фильтров.
// Если не указан, то используется FILTER_DEFAULT, который равнозначен FILTER_UNSAFE_RAW. Это значит, что по умолчанию не применяется никакого фильтра.
// http://php.net/manual/ru/function.filter-input.php

$doctor = filter_input(INPUT_POST, 'doctor', FILTER_VALIDATE_INT);    

if (!empty($_POST) // Данные пришли по POST
/* Тут неплохобы проверить введенные данные */) {
    try {
        $dbh = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=Registry', 'root');
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo "Нет соединения с базой данных";
    }
    try {

        switch ($doctor) {
            case 1 :
                $table = "therapist";
                break;
            case 2:
                $table = "dentist";
                break;
            default :
                // Что делаем, если пришел неверный код доктора?
                break;
        }

        $dbh->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        $dbh->beginTransaction();
        $sth = $dbh->prepare("INSERT INTO `$table` (name, surname, middlename, dateofbirth, policynumber, snils) VALUES (:name, :surname, :middlename, :dateofbirth, :policynumber, :snils)");

        // Для вставки параметров в запрос PDO есть специальные методы
        $sth->bindParam(':name', $name, PDO::PARAM_STR); // Где у вас $name объявлен??
        $sth->bindParam(':surname', $surname, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':middlename', $middlename, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':dateofbirth', $dateofbirth, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $sth->bindParam(':policynumber', $policynumber, PDO::PARAM_INT); // Полис и снилс, вроде бы, только из циферок состоят
        $sth->bindParam(':snils', $snils, PDO::PARAM_INT);

        $sth->execute();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        $dbh->rollBack();
    }
    header('Refresh:5; URL=http://localhost/site/site.html');
    echo 'Данные были полученны';
    {
        $dbh->commit();
    }
}
?>
```

**ЗЫ:** Ни когда не доверяйте данным пришедшим от пользователя.